# Why aren't Swagger services added to DI container conditionally (only in development)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

The default template of ASP.NET Core Web API is given as follows.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Why are the following two statements not enabled only in development?
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

// Others are removed for the sake of simplicity.

app.Run();
```

As you can see, `UseSwagger()` and `UseSwaggerUI()` are activated only in development.

## Question

I am curious why `AddEndpointsApiExplorer()` and `AddSwaggerGen()` are not activated only in development as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [What's new in ASP.NET Core 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-5.0?view=aspnetcore-6.0#web-api), you can see the Configure inject the  `IWebHostEnvironment`.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json",
                         "WebApp1 v1"));
    }
          ...
 }
```

In .net6 , from [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#startup-conventions)The default ASP.NET Core web app templates call WebApplication.CreateBuilder. The ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value overrides DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);   
 ...  
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

Generally speaking , configuration will probably be a simple and more intuitive route to handling different behaviour based on environment. So you don't need to add Swagger services to DI container conditionally.

However the dependency injection container is also a great point to switch out your services.
You can  use below code to add Swagger services to DI container conditionally.

```
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

if(builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
}
```

Result:

[image]